# Cross Domain Ajax Call in Atom Shell

Tags: cors, electron

We are working with Atom Shell (Currently known as [electron](https://github.com/atom/electron)) to wrap a web application as desktop app and having trouble making cross domain ajax calls due to CORS restriction.

We also tried [nw.js](http://nwjs.io/) (Formerly known as Node-Webkit) and we had no problem making cross domain ajax call with it. Does Atom Shell (Electron) restrict cross domain calls by default?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the webpage is loaded in "file://" mode and not served by an http server, you can make ajax calls by default.

If you still have troubles with CORS restrictions, you can set this option to the browser-window object :

```
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
var win = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: { webSecurity: false }
});
```

Comment: This will turn off all web-security, correct? I wonder if there is a way to add a single domain as "trusted" origin instead of this global wildcard.

Comment: Note the syntax has changed for this, the dashes have been dropped. It should now be `webPreferences` and `webSecurity`

Answer (score 9):

There are two problems here

CORS restrictions, which prevent the client from initiating a request, and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header which is set by the server.

The first problem is solved as mentioned by setting the web-security options on the Browser-window object.

```
"webPreferences" : {
    "webSecurity" : false
},
```

The second issue whereby Electron actually sends 'file://' as the value of the Origin in the request does not have a solution as far as I can tell.
Your options are to allow 'file://' or '*' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (server side).

I have actually requested that setting the origin on requests be allowed but I suspect it will not get much traction.

Comment: I have set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`. I think for some reason chrome does not like the fact that the header is not a valid domain name.

Answer (score 7):

Solutions' updated syntax:

```js
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
var win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {webSecurity: false}
});
```